# Problem with calculating Harmonic Numbers

Tags: special-functions, summation, precision-and-accuracy

I have tried to take a series of Harmonic Numbers using mathematica but there have been issues in calculations.

So far when I computed the sums at a small value range such as

```
1 + Sum[(-1)^n*HarmonicNumber[1.2, -(2*n + 1)]/(2*n + 1)!, {n, 0, 1000}]
(* Out: 1.049613536458448 *)
```

However when I multiply the exponent by 2, (after the first comma in the brackets).

```
1 + Sum[(-1)^n*HarmonicNumber[1.2, -2*(2*n + 1)]/(2*n + 1)!, {n, 0, 1000}]
(* Out: -1.97924×10^269 *)
```

I know that because of the factorial values and of (-1)^n that there is no way the sums can reach such a magnitude.

Is there some way I can increase the precision of the calculation to get the actual result?

Even at

`1 + Sum[(-1)^n*HarmonicNumber[1.2, -2*(2*n + 1)]/(2*n + 1)!, {n, 0, 5}]
 (* Out: 4.22911×10^7*)`

At Wolfram Alpha Pro I got instead:

`1 + Sum[(-1)^n*HarmonicNumber[1.2, -2*(2*n + 1)]/(2*n + 1)!, {n, 0, 5}]
 (* Out: 2.15329*)`

Comment: @ Arbuja Your statement "I know that because of the factorial values that there is no way the sums can reach such a magnitude." is not true since HarmonicNumber increases with the faculty of the negative second argument. Hence you must write (4*n+1)! in the denominator to cancel this growth.

Comment: Sorry I made an editing mistake!

Comment: The precision of your calculation is limited by the precision of its arguments, i.e. the `1.2` in the argument to `HarmonicNumber` that is automatically associated with `MachinePrecision` since you didn't specify otherwise. You could try and increase the precision of that argument. For instance using 35 digits of precision: ``1 + Sum[(-1)^n*HarmonicNumber[1.2`35, -2*(2*n + 1)]/(2*n + 1)!, {n, 0, 5}]`` returns $2.0469145021$. Your calculation going out to $n=1000$ will require A LOT MORE digits to get a meaningful result.

Comment: @MarcoB Is there an easier way to get a meaningful result? I notice with integers for x I can go up to 100 to get a precise answer but with fractions in x I have to take it MUCH FURTHER. Also how do I no the answers is actually precise?